# optaplanner cloud balancing example - network interfaces

Tags: drools, optaplanner

How can I change the Optaplanner cloud balancing domain example with so that it will contain network interfaces?

Several virtual interfaces can be connected to a single host interface,
each has its own requirement such as bandwidth,  network type( VLAN, VxLAN, etc). I need to check that all virtual interfaces are matched by there type and that the total bandwidth won't exceeds the physical interface bandwidth.

In other words, I need to match several virtual interfaces to a single (or more) physical interface in the same host.

is the following model is OK? link --> 
[Cloud planning model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhqd.png)

How can I initialize 'VirtualInterface's' each time there was a change/swap with VirtualMachine?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you'd just:

- add an `int interfaceSize` on `Computer.java`
- add an `int minimumInterfaceSize` on `Process.java`

and then add a hard constraint in the DRL to insure that `interfaceSize >= minimumInterfaceSize`.

Comment: @Geoffrey-De_Smet thanks for your answer, I updated my question, check it pls